# for loop not returning result

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i'm creating a search bar and i'm looping an array . and i'm using

```
  attr('placeholder' array) // jQuery
```

to display array result in my search bar . but it's returning the last index of the array .

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput"/>
```

Js

```
var inputSearch     = $('#searchInput');
var searchArray     = ['s','e','a','r','c','h'];
var searchReturn    = '';



    for(var i = 0 ; i < searchArray.length ; i++){

        searchReturn = searchArray[i];
        console.log(searchReturn);
        $(inputSearch).attr('placeholder', searchReturn);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try appending the text, you're just assigning each time

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < searchArray.length ; i++){

    searchReturn = searchReturn + searchArray[i];
    console.log(searchReturn);
    $(inputSearch).attr('placeholder', searchReturn);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution and easiest way is

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < searchArray.length ; i++){

searchReturn += searchArray[i];
console.log(searchReturn);
$(inputSearch).attr('placeholder', searchReturn);
```

}